# Keras - Load images from generator into memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to load my images into memory utilizing the image augmentation opions provided by the keras `ImageDataGenerator`. As such, I am creating my generator like so:

```
testgen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=keras.applications.mobilenet.preprocess_input)

test_generator = testgen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df_test, 
                                             classes=class_labels, 
                                             directory=data_dir,
                                             x_col=training_on, 
                                             y_col=target, 
                                             has_ext=True, 
                                             class_mode="categorical", 
                                             target_size=(224,224), 
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             seed = 1,
                                             shuffle=False)
```

Now I can get a single batch using:

```
x,y = next(test_generator)
```

However, I would like to store the entire dataset (possibly augmented) into `x` and `y`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xTrain = list()
yTrain = list()
for i in range(len(test_generator)):
    x,y = test_generator[i] 
    xTrain.append(x)
    yTrain.append(y)

xTrain = np.array(xTrain)
yTrain = np.array(yTrain)
```

Alternative:

```
xTrain = list()
yTrain = list()
for i in range(number_of_batches):
    x,y = next(test_generator)
    xTrain.append(x)
    yTrain.append(y)

xTrain = np.array(xTrain)
yTrain = np.array(yTrain)
```

Notice that this will not result in significant augmentation. You will end up with the same number of samples as the original data.

For augmentation to really work you need to train over and over with this generator so it produces many different random versions of the same images.

Comment: Thanks so much! Also thank you for the comment regarding the amount of augmentation. I wonder if it would be possible (or even make sense) to use a second ImageDataGenerator with the .flow argument to augment (xTrain,yTrain) during training. Then of course I would not augment xTrain, yTrain upon first loading. Does that work or would it cause trouble during training?

Comment: You can use any number of generators you want. But for augmentation, only one is enough. The second cycle will be different from the first cycle.